# How to copy skill property from each object in the 2nd and set that skill property for each object in the 1st array based on property id? (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

I have 2 arrays of objects. Both arrays have the same length and the same id properties for each object:

```
const arr1 = [{id:1, name:'Dave', email:'email1@gmail.com'}, {id:2, name:'Jane', email:'email2@gmail.com'}]
const arr2 = [{id:1, profession:'programmer', skill:'JS'}, {id:2, profession:'Sales person', skill:'sales'}]
```

How can I copy skill property for each object from arr2 and set it in the first array of object by checking the related property id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[For each](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) value in `arr1`, try to [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) a corresponding value in `arr2` and update the skill property accordingly:

```
arr1.forEach(v1 => v1.skill = arr2.find(v2 => v1.id === v2.id)?.skill);
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const arr1 = [
  {id:1, name:'Dave', email:'email1@gmail.com'},
  {id:2, name:'Jane', email:'email2@gmail.com'}
];
const arr2 = [
  {id:1, profession:'programmer', skill:'JS'},
  {id:2, profession:'Sales person', skill:'sales'}
];

arr1.forEach(v1 => v1.skill = arr2.find(v2 => v1.id === v2.id)?.skill);

console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: Just a side note: this would add a property `skill: undefined` to all objects in `arr1` for which there is no corresponding object in `arr2` (wich should never happen, if we accept the OP statement that "_Both arrays have the same length and the same id properties for each object_") or whose corresponding object in `arr2` has no `skill` property.

Comment: Yeah. Having a `skill` property that is `undefined` when no match is found seemed reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 1, name: "Dave", email: "email1@gmail.com"}, {id: 2, name: "Jane", email: "email2@gmail.com"}];
const arr2 = [{id: 1, profession: "programmer", skill: "JS"}, {id: 2, profession: "Sales person", skill: "sales"}];

console.log(arr1);

arr2.forEach((el2) => {
  let result = arr1.find((el1) => el1.id === el2.id)
  if (result) {
   result.skill= el2.skill;
  }
})

console.log(arr1);
```